# How to publish Data Reviewer service in ArcGIS Enterprise 11

Tags: arcgis-server, installation, arcgis-enterprise, data-reviewer

How can publish data reviewer service in ArcGIS Enterprise 11, because in ArcGIS Enterprise 11 doesn´t exist a [Data Reviewer for Server](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/data-reviewer/latest/help/what-is-arcgis-data-reviewer-for-server.htm) installer?